# Is it possible to clip a table column?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve something like this.

```
table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  clip: rect(0px, 10px, 100px, 0px);
}
```

It is ment to "hide" the first `10px` of the third column of a table.

At first try this was not working, even with setting `table-layout: fixed`. Is it possible to solve this somehow?

I'd like to experiment with this technique to implement fixed columns with "virtual" horizontal scrolling.

Comment: `clip` property is deprecated in favor of `clip-path` Not sure though if good 'ol tables handle that...

Comment: you are misusing this CSS rule http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/16/understanding-the-css-clip-property/  https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/clip where absolute breaks the table-layout for sure :) You'll need here an extra wrapper, negative margins and overflow:hidden ...

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks for your hints. By a "wrapper" do you mean separating fixed columns into a new table, of do you possibly have some other ideas without table separation?

Comment: i posted the tip into an answer if that fits your needs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tip from my comment

- use an extra container and use negative to reduce virtually its width to none but kept in the flow.
- give a padding or a width to your td.

it seems you want to show only a portion of 10px width

approach selecting clipping from the left

```css
table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) div {
  margin: 0 -999px 0 -10px;
  /* here -10px brings element in padding area of td and shows the first 10 px , to clip at 10px instead 0px do -20px idem for top margin */
  max-height: 100%;/* eventually & overflow:hidden ? */
  color:white
}
table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: purple;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table > tbody > tr > td {
  background-color: orange;
}
/* example new clipping coordonates */
table + table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) div {
  margin: -0.2em -999px 0 -3.75em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First Column</td>
      <td>
        <div>Second Column</div>
      </td>
      <td>Third Column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First Column</td>
      <td>
        <div>Second Column</div>
      </td>
      <td>Third Column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

approach selecting clipping from the right

```css
table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) div {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 -9999px;
  color: white
}
table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: purple;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table > tbody > tr > td {
  background-color: orange;
}
/* example new clipping coordonates */

table + table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) div {
  margin: 0 -20px 0 -9999px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First Column</td>
      <td>
        <div>Second Column</div>
      </td>
      <td>Third Column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First Column</td>
      <td>
        <div>Second Column</div>
      </td>
      <td>Third Column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Interesting alternative, I was actually thinking about something like this but dropped it because of the level of the added DOM and CSS complexity. However, technically it's valid, so I'm gonna accept your answer. Anyway what I wanted is to show the "last" 10px, not the first, but it shouldn't be a big deal either I think.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási to clip  from the other side, you need another approach/technique (wich allows to hide the overflow from the opposite direction --- only end is shown, instead start): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKZqrV then, negative margin on -right woks, if you want to clip further from right

Comment: added a transition on hover so hidden content can show up on hover, to see how it works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKZqrV

Answer (score 0):

The CSS provided actually targets the second column, not the third.

```css
table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  clip: rect(0px, 10px, 100px, 0px);
  background-color: purple;
  
}
table > tbody > tr > td {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First Column</td>
      <td>Second Column</td>
      <td>Third Column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u6pvf6wL/

Clip has been deprecated and replaced by clip-path. Please check http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20clip-path - you may not want to pursue this path if you need to support IE in all its delightful quirkiness. The syntax for clip-path is slightly different. You can find examples documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path.

(Embrace the new clip-path option, clip is only applied to absolutely positioned elements. Managing a table with absolutely positioned td's sounds like a world of hurt. While I love CSS-only solutions, this is really a great use-case for a little javascript.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't aware of the need of absolute positioning. Of course I don't want to mess with that. What I would really like is to keep one table, without separating the fixed columns in their separate table (something like eg. jqGrid fixedColumns work), but I feel like it's kind of impossible.